# how to check if file exist in a folder on ftp in c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

i want to check if some files exists in a folder on ftp then do specific task
i have the following methos for files check

```
public static bool CheckFileExistOnFTP(string ServerUri, string FTPUserName, string FTPPassword)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
        //request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
       // request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;

        try
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and i call that method on formload

```
if (FTPUtility.CheckFileExistOnFTP("ftp://ip address/Requests/", "edexcrawler", "edexcrawler123"))
            {
                btnUploadRequest.Visible = true;
                btnUploadRequest.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                btnUploadRequest.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

            }
```

Comment: Based on your other question to get a list of files from ftp, you can check if the file you want to check is in that list.

Comment: infact i m not checking a particular file, i just want to check the folder if there is some file exist then to show or hide a button

Comment: So simply check `utility.ListFiles().Count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584189/how-to-display-files-from-ftp-server-to-a-local-windows-application-gridview/32587522#32587522) to get a list of files from ftp,  you can check if the file you want to check is in that list:

```
Var fileNameToCkeck = "myfile.txt";

var utility= new FtpUtility();
utility.UserName = "...";
utility.Password = "...";
utility.Path = "...";

If (utility.ListFiles().Contains(fileNameToCkeck))
{
     //The file exists
}
```

Or if you want to know if that path has any file:

```
If (utility.ListFiles().Count() > 0)
{
     //The folder contains files
}
```

And here is the code for FtpUtility

```
public class FtpUtility
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListFiles()
    {
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Path);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) == false)
                    {
                        var fileName = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }).Last();
                        if (!fileName.StartsWith("."))
                            files.Add(fileName);
                    }
                }
                return files;
            }
        }
    }
}
```